# How to remove/enhance/change the form submit data using standard submit event and jquery, before the actual submit happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

Is it possible to extract data from a form, say:

```
<form action="/search/search" data-remote="true" data-type="json" id="search_form" method="get">

  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input name="search[req][text][e]" type="hidden" value="false">
      <input id="search_req_text_e" name="search[req][text][e]" type="checkbox" value="true">
    </span>
    <input id="search_req_text_v" name="search[req][text][v]" type="text" value="">
  </div>

  <button id="fire_search" type="submit">Search</button>

</form>
```

I thought about jQuery's `.submit()` method. But how to extract and change the url from the event?

```
$('#search_flickr_panel_body form').submit(function(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

I don't see in Chrome DevTools any url in the printed event object

I would like to remove the text fields which are unchecked.

Maybe .attr('disabled', 'true') would be a variant for remove, but how to change the data, without change it in the text field, only in submit url?

## Update:

I have over 100 such input fields in the form, so to just send all of them even if only one is checked is not so nice (too much useless data making the communication overhead)

## Update2:

I want not only be able to remove the unchecked data from the submit data, but also be able to change this data before submit(e.g. add a prefix to the values, add new parameters), so that I can effect the resulted url (with data).

Comment: To clarify: Your want to remove search_req_text_v from the posted data if search_req_text_e is unchecked?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just not use that value on the serverside ?

Comment: it would, **but if the form is really huge** (I have over 100 inputs) - it would not really good to have such communication overhead if only one input is checked

Answer (score 0):

This will disable all the text fields that have associated checkboxes unticked...

```
$(function() {
    $('#search_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(".input-group").each(function() {
            $(this).find("input:text").prop("disabled", !$(this).find("input:checkbox")[0].checked);
        });

        this.submit();

        $(".input-group input:text").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

The disabled ones should not be submitted with the rest of the form.

Comment: it is a solution for removing the data. but how to change it without changing the form? or should I use then custom ajax request and handle it so or are there any other options with a standard submit event?

Comment: The form will be reloaded due to submitting the page, so your server should handle the state of the elements, not the client.

Comment: no, it will not be reloaded: I have a `data-remote=true` attribute, so it is an AJAX Request

Comment: Try the above.  It stops the submit method being called, makes the changes to the text fields, submits the form using the native method and then sets all the text boxes back to being enabled.

Comment: some of them could be disabled, that was the point - not to send the useless (unchecked) data

Comment: yep, it works, but only for removing the useless data. Is it possible to **change what is going to submit manually**, say, adding a prefixes to each value?

Comment: So not all the text fields are enabled by default?  When the submit button is clicked there could be a mixed state for the text fields?

Comment: the form is empty and all checkboxes are unchecked by default. Mixed state?

Comment: Let me get this straight... when you click the submit button, are all the text boxes enabled?

Comment: So the above code will disable text fields that have unticked checkboxes, submit the form data, and then enable all the text fields again.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: not all. I wrote, that I want to remove/change/enhance (e.g. add a parameter, add prefixes to the values) the data is going to submit, without changing the values in the input fields.

Comment: You need to be very clear about every step that you require then, in the question (not comments), as your question is very unclear.

Comment: ok, I see - it is not that clear, but still: `...and change/remove it when submit?`, so remove is only one of that what I asked for. anyway - thank you very much for the code and the conversation - I got some points for other places in my code to change! if you know how to change the data without handling the whole ajax request manually that would be great to know

Comment: That's as easy to do as disabling the fields, but without knowing what you actually want to do to the data it's not possible to help you.  You must update the question.

Comment: does it sound better now?